# Displaying the post after entered

Tags: php, html, css

I have some HTML and PHP code, which is responsible for basically, when some text is entered into a field, it should display as a post (which I have already made partially), and I have written the PHP code responsible for database insertion as well. However, the only thing I want to do is, when the user types in the field and clicks post, the post should display. So for that I tried some code, however it isn't working. When filled in and the post button is clicked, the post isn't displaying. What to do? Code:

PHP:

```
<?php

session_start();

// Making Connection To The Database

$dbHost = "localhost";
$dbUser = "root";
$dbPass = "";
$database = "signup";

$connection = mysqli_connect($dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPass, $database) or die ("Sorry, we could not connect to the database");

// Posting System

if (!empty($_POST['postContent'])) {
  $post = $_POST['postContent'];
  $firstname = $_SESSION['firstname'];
  $lastname = $_SESSION['lastname'];

  $sql = "INSERT INTO posts (firstname, lastname, body, date_posted) VALUES (?, ?, ?, NOW())";
  $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($connection);
  // nested if statement
  if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
    echo "";
  } else {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss", $firstname, $lastname, $post);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
  }
} else {
  echo "";
}

?>
```

HTML & PHP:

```
<style>

.postPFP {
  margin-left: 680px;
  width: 70px;
  position: fixed;
  margin-top: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.info {
  margin-left: 756px;
  position: fixed;
  font-family: 'Rajdhani';
  font-weight: bolder;
  margin-top: 25px;
}

.postOptions {
  position: fixed;
  width: 70px;
  margin-left: 1176px;
  margin-top: 16px;
}

.thepost {
  margin-top: 55px;
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
}

</style>

<div class="thepost">
  <?php

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM posts";
  $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
  if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

  ?>
  <div class="postFormat">
    <img src="img/pfp.png" alt="pfp" onclick="location.href='profile.php'" class="postPFP">
    <b><div class="info"><?php echo $firstname . "&nbsp;" . $lastname ?></div></b>
    <img src="img/options.png" alt="postOptions" class="postOptions">
    <hr style="margin-top: 85px; width: 600px; position: fixed; margin-left: 663px; border:1px solid black; border-radius: 10px">
    <hr style="margin-top: 85px; width: 0px; height: 215px; position: fixed; margin-left: 1150px; border: 1px solid black; border-radius: 10px">
    <hr style="margin-top: 300px; width: 600px; position: fixed; margin-left: 663px; border:1px solid black; border-radius: 10px">
    <p style="margin-left: 670px; margin-top: 95px; position: fixed; font-family: 'Rajdhani'"><?php echo $row["body"]; ?></p>
  </div>
  <?php

  }
}

  ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Doesn't it has to be `$row['firstname']`?

Comment: 1. Are you sure all the data for the post is properly saved in the database? 2. Where does `$firstname` and `$lastname` come from? The DB result is in `$row`. 3. Where do you define `$connection` in the second code block? Or are all the code on the same page? 4. Can you see the HTML / Have you checked that your SELECT actually returns any results? Please do some basic debugging to narrow the issue down.

Comment: Ok, $firstname and $lastname are already defined as sessions, under $row['firstname'] and $row['lastname'], getting the data from the login page, on a separate file. Right now, the only problem is to display the post ($row['body']) after it is filled and the post button is clicked for which I already made the HTML layout of the post to display, and the SELECT * FROM posts php code. How do I check if my SELECT returns any results Magnus? And yes my connection is defined. My code is all on the same page.